# Issue with delayed for loop not iterating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a function in JavaScript that uses jQuery to grab a list of image src's from a bunch of li's in a ul (unfortunately they cant change this in the backend), and I'm trying to replace a certain image src every few seconds with one from the list.

I have tried using jQuery `delay()`, functionTimeout, and some other things and I can't seem to get it to work.

Does anyone know why this isn't working, or know a better way to do this?

```
function sponsorRotator(sponsorImg, sponsorUl) {
var ulLength = $(sponsorUl + " li").length;
for (var i=0;i<ulLength;i++)    {
    setTimeout( function() {
        var imgSrc = $(sponsorUl + " li").eq( i+1 ).children("img").attr( "src" );
        $(sponsorImg).attr('src',imgSrc);
        console.log(i);
    }, 1000);
}
}

sponsorRotator("#image", "#list");
```

I have the code on JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/pPe3u/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't loop at all. I would set my timer like so, incrementing the index with each call to the function.

```
function sponsorRotator(sponsorImg, sponsorUl) {
  var ulLength = $(sponsorUl + " li").length;
  var i = - 1;
  var timer = function (i) {
    var imgSrc = $(sponsorUl + " li").eq(i).children("img").attr("src");
    $(sponsorImg).attr('src', imgSrc);
    setTimeout(function () {
        i = (i === ulLength - 1) ? 0 : i + 1;
        timer(i);
    }, 1000);
  };
  timer(i);
}

sponsorRotator("#image", "#list");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/SPkgF/).

Comment: So how would I go about making the loop restart at 0 once it goes through them all so it repeats

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are firing the anonymous function at a later time, so the i variable will be the one after the for loop is completed. You need to create a copy of the i variable at each iteration that is enclosed in the function. I have done so using bind:

```
function sponsorRotator(sponsorImg, sponsorUl) {
var ulLength = $(sponsorUl + " li").length;
for (var i=0;i<ulLength;i++)    {
    setTimeout( function(i) { // i passed as parameter
        var imgSrc = $(sponsorUl + " li").eq( i+1 ).children("img").attr( "src" );
        $(sponsorImg).attr('src',imgSrc);
        console.log(i);
    }.bind(null,i), 1000); // bind magic
}
}

sponsorRotator("#image", "#list");
```